# How to set cron for every min in godaddy server.

Tags: php, yii

I need to execute a cron job every minute, is it possible in godaddy hosting? is there a way of configuring it?
thanks.

Comment: * * * * * path/to/php path/to/script - every minute cron, open ssh, type crontab -e, add this line, save. Check - write crontab -l and watch if its added.

Answer (score 1):

Using GoDaddy's Cron Job Manager, you ***could*** create six individual cron jobs that execute twice hourly. You could then set which twice hourly minutes to execute each task at:

- **Job 1:** x:0-30
- **Job 2:** x:5-35
- **Job 3:** x:10-40
- **Job 4:** x:15-45
- **Job 5:** x:20-50
- **Job 6:** x:25-55

Answer (score 0):

This is a every minute cron comment

```
 * * * * * path/to/php path/to/script - every minute cron
```

Check this Procedure Link. It will help you lot

please go throw  [this link](http://support.godaddy.com/help/article/3548/working-with-cron-jobs)

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you can set as describe in GoDaddy official site to set different cron job form you account manager.

Please see [this link](http://support.godaddy.com/help/article/3548/working-with-cron-jobs)

It is very good document to implement cron job in GoDaddy.

Comment: down voter .. what's wrong with answer ? i am just giving you clear example.